# Tha jar is not executing

Tags: java, apache-spark, sbt, sbt-assembly

I have submitted the following command

```
$java -cp spark-kafka-fraud-detection-assembly-1.0.jar com.jcalc.feed.CCStreamingFeed 50
```

Its seems like started executing.I can see the following things in my console

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.lib.MutableMetricsFactory).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

Its remain in same state for long time .Nothing got executed expect the above three lines . Can any one help me .Thanks!

Comment: Please provide more information. Does your code generate any output to console or file?

Comment: yes my code will generate output and printed on console .My code is simple  kafka producer ,it will display the topics name and message on the console